# Using Regex in Lexical Analyzer (Java)

Tags: java, regex, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I am working on building a lexical analyzer for a fictional XML-style language and I'm currently trying to turn the following lexical specification into Java code:

```
Name -> Initial Other*
Initial -> Letter | _ | :
Other -> Initial | Digit | - | .
String -> " (Char | ')* " | '(Char | ")* '
Data -> Char+
Char -> Ordinary | Special | Reference
Ordinary -> NOT (< | > | " | ' | &) 
Special -> &lt; | &gt; | &quot; | &apos; | &amp;
Reference -> &#(Digit)+; | &#x(Digit|a...f|A...F)+;
Letter -> a...z | A...Z
Digit -> 0...9
```

I'm no expert, but I do know I have to use regular expressions for these. So my Tokenizer now looks like this:

```
public Tokenizer(String str) {
    this.tokenContents = new ArrayList<TokenContent>();
    this.str = str;

    // Name = Initial Other*
    String initial = "[a-zA-Z] | _ | :";
    String other = initial + " | [0-9] | - | \\.";
    String name = initial + "(" + other + ")*";
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile(name), TokenType.NAME));
    // String = " " (Char | ')* " | ' (Char | ")* '
    String ordinary = "(?!(< | > | \" | ' | &))";
    String special = "&lt; | &gt; | &quot; | &apos; | &amp;";
    String reference = "&#[0-9]+; | &#x([0-9] | [a-fA-F])+;";
    String character = ordinary + " | " + special + " | " + reference;
    String string = "\"(" + character + " | " + "')* \" | ' (\"" + character + " | " + "\")* '";
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile(string), TokenType.STRING));
    // Data = Char+
    String data = character + "+"; 
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile(data), TokenType.DATA)); 
    // The symbol <
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile("<"), TokenType.LEFT_TAG));
    // The symbol >
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile(">"), TokenType.RIGHT_TAG));
    // The symbol </
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile("</"), TokenType.LEFT_TAG_SLASH));
    // The symbol />
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile("/>"), TokenType.RIGHT_TAG_SLASH));  
    // The symbol = 
    tokenContents.add(new TokenContent(Pattern.compile("="), TokenType.EQUALS));    
}
```

For simplicity, you can see I have modularized my regular expressions according to the specification above. However, after several test cases of running the lexer on an example input file, I get parsing errors. I believe it might be my regular expressions, so **I would like some suggestions on how I can correctly translate the above specification into code and fix my Tokenizer.**

My tokens are `Name`, `String`, `Data`, `<`, `>`, `</`, `/>`, and `=`. They are all specified in an `enum` class that isn't displayed here. An example input file is:

```
<recipe name="bread" prep_time="5 mins" cook_time="3 hours">
   <title>Basic bread</title>
   <ingredient amount="3" unit="cups">Flour</ingredient>
   <ingredient amount="0.25" unit="ounce">Yeast</ingredient>
   <ingredient amount="1.5" unit="cups" state="warm">Water</ingredient>
   <ingredient amount="1" unit="teaspoon">Salt</ingredient>
   <instructions>
     <step>Mix all ingredients together.</step>
     <step>Knead thoroughly.</step>
     <step>Cover with a cloth, and leave for one hour in warm room.</step>
     <step>Knead again.</step>
     <step>Place in a bread baking tin.</step>
     <step>Cover with a cloth, and leave for one hour in warm room.</step>
     <step>Bake in the oven at 350&#x00B0; F for 30 minutes.</step>
   </instructions>
</recipe>
```

I've never worked with regular expressions much before so this is a first for me. I would really appreciate any input that could help.

Comment: Please post some of the test cases that you're trying to parse.

Comment: Added an example input file. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use simple XML parsing ?

Comment: Not an option in this case.

Comment: What information are you trying to retrieve using these RegEx, as none of them are for XML tags.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the individual tokens matching Name, String, Data, <, >, </,  />, and =, as described in the specification I posted. The language resembles XML but it's not supposed to be the same. I feel my problem is in the regular expressions, so I'd like to know how to fix them.

Comment: You are mixing Lexical Analysis with Parsing.  Lexical Analysis would not have productions depending on other productions, such as `Char -> Ordinary | Special | Reference; Ordinary -> NOT (< | > | " | ' | &)`   That is a grammar.  A lexical specification matches regular expressions to token types ONLY.

Comment: Using regular expressions for lexers is common, using java-Patterns is not. Java Patterns are based on non-deterministic finite automata (NFA) and this makes lexing very expensive. You may be interested in lexing with a DFA-regular expression, e.g. [rexlex](https://github.com/almondtools/rexlex).

Comment: @JimGarrison Assuming that `Ordinary` itself is not meant to be a token (it would be very unusual/unhelpful to have a token like that - also note that OP did not add those patterns into `tokenContents`), it is perfectly fine (and in fact common) for a lexer to contain auxiliary definitions like `DIGIT` or `LETTER` that are then used by token definitions.

Comment: @sepp2k You assume correctly. I've already specified what the tokens are.

Comment: It would help if you told us which tokens you get for your example input (especially the part where it differs from what you should get) and if you could provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run ourselves. But at a glance I'd say the problem is your use of negative lookahead in `ordinary`. A regex that contains only lookahead will consume exactly 0 characters.

Comment: So did this fix the problem or does it still not work?

Comment: @sepp2k No. I suppose the question is a little too narrow, but I'm starting to think using regex may not work in this case. I've since completely rewritten the scanner and got better-but -still-wrong results. Comments, for one, don't seem to be recognized as such and therefore aren't ignored.

Comment: And again I'm not allowed to use any sort of auto-generating tool which is what people (understandably) tend to recommend on SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
String ordinary = "(?!(< | > | \" | ' | &))";
```

This pattern won't do what you want it to. Lookahead is a feature that is used to make a pattern match only if it's followed (or, in the case of negative lookahead as you use here, *not* followed) by a specific pattern. The lookahead itself does not consume any input.

Take for example the pattern `[a-z]+(?=\s)`. This will match a sequence of letters that are followed by a whitespace, but not the whitespace itself. So the pattern would match the "abc" in "abc def" and would not match anything in "abc_def". But either way the match would not include the space. If you use this in a tokenizer (that also has a rule for whitespace), this will cause "abc def " to be tokenized as "abc", " ", "def", " ", rather than "abc ", "def ". So that's useful.

But in your case your entire pattern is lookahead. So if you tokenized something using your rule, the result would look more like "", "", ... ad infinitum. That's less useful.

What you want is a negative character class, which is created using `[^...]` where the `...` is a list of characters or character ranges as you'd use with a normal character class. It matches exactly one character as long as that character is not in the specified list. Using this, your regex would look like this:

```
String ordinary = "[^<>\"'&]";
```